# Process inside docker container not receiving signals?

Tags: docker, signals

I have a process in a docker container that is supposed to log a thread dump (on stdout) when shut down.  However when `docker stop` is called on it, no output happens.

It seems that either the process doesn't receive the TERM signal or the output is detached before the shutdown is complete.

I'm using only a `CMD` (no `ENTRYPOINT`) in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD java ${MY_JAVA_OPTS} my-uberjar.jar
```

How do I get output on shutdown working?

Answer (score 1):

The entry point of the docker container is a shell calling that CMD, because it is in *shell form*.

This form of calling doesn't propagate signals, however.

You need to call the process using `exec`, which can be done by either using the *exec form*:

```
CMD ["java", "-Doption=value", "my-uberjar.jar"]
```

or by using `exec` explicitly:

```
CMD exec java ${MY_JAVA_OPTS} my-uberjar.jar
```

This results in the shell replacing itself with the started process, which then receives the signals.

The *exec form* doesn't do shell expansion, though (because there is no shell),
so if you need that, you'd have to wrap a shell invocation and `exec` again:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec", "java", "${MY_JAVA_OPTS}", ...
```

or use the *shell form* with `exec` as above.